# How would one go about blocking specific domains/ip addresses using Python?

Tags: python, dns, ip, block, ip-address

After browsing for several hours, I'm completely stumped on how to prevent Windows 7 from accessing specific addresses. This is basically a blacklist program. Do I need to use a module meant for packets or something?

**Edit:** My goal is to block certain domains/ips across all browsers and any other apps that access the internet. So a system wide block is preferable.

Comment: Its helpful when you include the code you've written or the things you've  tried when asking a question. It gives people a good starting point for providing help to you.

Comment: Are you trying to add new rules to the system's firewall? If not, what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: At first I was trying to use a Chrome extension that blocked certain websites, and I would have python just modify the extension's blacklist. This wasn't a very solid solution however and I can't seem to find any resources that allow me to modify Win7's firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Firewall settings](http://www.speakcomputers.com/windows7/firewall.aspx)

It doesn't mention blocking particular addresses on that page, but you can create a custom rule and under the 'Scope' Step, you can have it apply to certain remote IP addresses. This doesn't really solve your problem for particular domain names (as they could have multiple IP's) but it's a start.

If you wanted to tie that in with your python program I believe the relevant commands are along the lines of a system command called 'netsh'. In particular, "netsh advfirewall firewall add", which I don't know the arguments for.

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I need. I can write a portion of the program that looks up all the ip addresses for a given domain. Thank You!